# Tip Calculator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    tip_percent=float(meal_cost * (tip_percent / 100))
    tax_percent=float(meal_cost * (tax_percent / 100))
    total_cost=meal_cost + tip_percent + tax_percent
    return (total_cost)
print(solve(12, 20, 8))
```

The answer should be 15, but the above is giving 12.0. Not sure why. 
when I tried printing tip_percent, it's giving 0.0.

tip_percent calculated as follows:

```
float(meal_cost * (tip_percent / 100))
```

I'm learning Python at the beginning stage.

Comment: I am getting 15.36 with the same code.

Comment: Are you sure you're using python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are consistent with using Python 2. In Python 2 `/` is integer division if the numbers to divide are integers.  To force float math change `100` to `100.0`:

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    tip_percent=float(meal_cost * (tip_percent / 100.0))
    tax_percent=float(meal_cost * (tax_percent / 100.0))
    total_cost=meal_cost+tip_percent+tax_percent
    return total_cost
print(solve(12,20,8))
```

Or change to using Python 3.

#### Results:

```
15.36
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are testing with Python 2, which returns 12.0.
In Python 3 the same code would return 15.36.

The reason is Python changed how they handle division in Python 3.

For example:
 
3 / 2 = 1 (in Python 2.7.6)
3 / 2 = 1.5 (in Python 3.4.1)

To fix that divide by 100.0 (not by 100).
Exampels you could find here: https://riptutorial.com/python/example/2797/integer-division